# Use the favicon at the news box at timeline

Tags: facebook, icons, favicon

Why the apps just have the option to configurate one icon (16x16) to show at the users timeline? What about be possible to use the page favicon?

I work at a big media company and we have some diferents produts under our website. We wanted to show the page favicon at the users timeline to differentiate which product the user had visited.

Answer (score 0):

The icon Christian is talking about is an app icon on timeline. Not the image of the url. At this point is not possible to customize this icon by url. I work for a great portal with a lot of different trademarks. We are being forced to make an app for each one because of this issue.

Answer (score -1):

Facebook says the image must be at least 50x50 and no greater than 3.0:1 width:height aspect ratio.  So a 16x16 favicon will be ignored when making the post (although due to bad programming on the linter tool likes 16x16 images and tells you that it's just fine).